# Recommended practice for passing current user to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, postgresql

Given a model `Orderstatus` with attributes `private_status:string`, and `private_status_history:json`(I'm using Postgresql's *json*). I would like to record each status transition, together with the user who made the change.

Ideally it would be something like:

```rb
class Orderstatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :track_changes

  def track_changes
    changes = self.changes
    if self.private_status_changed?
      self.private_status_history_will_change!
      self.private_status_history.append({
                                 type: changes[:private_status],
                                 user: current_user.id
                                 })                
    end
  end
end


class OrderstatusController <ApplicationController
  def update
    if @status.update_attributes(white_params)
      # Good response
    else
      # Bad response
    end
  end
end

#Desired behaviour (process not run with console)
status = Orderstatus.new(private_status:'one')
status.private_status #=> 'one'
status.private_status_history #=> []
status.update_attributes({:private_status=>'two'}) #=>true
status.private_status #=> 'two'
status.private_status_history #=> [{type:['one','two'],user:32]
```

What would be the recommended practice to achieve this? Apart from the usual one using Thread. Or maybe, any suggestion to refactor the structure of the app?

Comment: On an unrelated note, is there a reason you're doing this manually as opposed to using something like [paper trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail)?

Comment: Thanks for the note. To be honest, paper-trail would certainly fit, but since for now this is the only attribute I need to keep track of; I'd rather do it manuall to avoid adding a new gem to the stack. Also, I was about interesting ways to achieve that  :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally settled for this option ( I hope it's not alarming to anyone :S)

```rb
class Orderstatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :track_changes
  attr_accessor :modifying_user

  def track_changes
    changes = self.changes
    if self.private_status_changed?
      newchange = {type:changes[:private_status],user: modifying_user.id}
      self.update_column(:private_status_history,
                       self.private_status_history.append(newchange))    
    end
  end
end


class OrderstatusController <ApplicationController
  def update
    @status.modifying_user = current_user # <---- HERE!
    if @status.update_attributes(white_params)
      # Good response
    else
      # Bad response
    end
  end
end
```

*Notes:*
- I pass the from the Controller to the Model through an instance attribute `modifying_user` of the class `Orderstatus`. That attribute is ofc not saved to the db.
- Change of method to append new changes to the history field. I.e. `attr_will_change! + save` to `update_column + append`